# Google Storage config

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to configure the `gsutil` command line tool for Google's Storage API but it doesn't seem to like it:

```
ahmeds:~ ahmed$ gsutil config
CommandException: OAuth2 is only supported when running under Python 2.6 or later
(unless additional dependencies are installed, see README for details);
you are running Python 2.7.2 (default, Nov 25 2011, 23:36:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)].
Use 'gsutil config -a' to create a config with Developer Key authentication credentials.
```

What could I be doing wrong? Do I need to reinstall Python?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to:
"Use 'gsutil config -a' to create a config with Developer Key authentication credentials" 
As suggested?

Comment: Yep, I then get `CommandException: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gslib/VERSION not found. Did you install the
complete gsutil software after the gsutil "update" command was implemented?` which is as magical.

Comment: try to search where gsutils is putted or try to install gsutil again

Answer (score 0):

I read the istructions and I tryied and in my case it's all right. I think the you forget to set the enviroment variable `PATH` or to restart the terminal emulator after that. Please let me know the output of `$echo $PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Gsutil looks for its dependencies in the same directory in which it was installed (all dependencies come bundled in the gsutil installation package). Knowing that, this line looks suspicious:

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gslib/VERSION not found.

because it indicates an attempt to find the VERSION file from the python site-packages tree, which is at odds with the logic noted above. It sounds to me like you may have an improperly installed gsutil package. I'd suggest re-installing from scratch. If, after re-installing, you are able to reproduce this problem, please post a brief summary of the installation steps you followed so we can try to provide additional assistance.